# Cashier Laravel error on create new Subscription

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to implements laravel cashier in my project.
I have laravel 5.5 and cashier 7.2.2.

I have a problem when I try to createNewSubscription.

In my controller I have:

```
$user = User::find(3);
$subscription = $user->newSubscription('Base', 'price_45asd456a1sa56sd4');
$subscription->create($token);
```

But I receive this error:

> "Call to a member function create() on null" on line 415 of /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Billable.php

The problem is that in trait return error in:

```
$card = $customer->sources->create(['source' => $token]);
```

Because  `$customer->sources` is null.
But why?

I can see that in my db the stripe_id is setted, and in dashboard of stripe the Customer is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with the same bug and was happening locally, but on production works. So I checked the Stripe API version that I'm using (the latest) so if you [check here](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27) you will see that "The `sources` property on Customers is no longer included by default" so probably this is why we're getting this error.